# Adding a Call to Action to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

Is it possible to add a [Call To Action](https://www.facebook.com/help/312169205649942) to a Facebook page via Open Graph?

Querying the page call_to_action field returns a nice:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (call_to_action) on node type (Page)
```

and in the official documentation there is no sign of this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, it is not possible to add the Call To Action with the Graph API. It may be possible in the future, follow the changelog to stay up to date: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog